# How to add more than one zone to DNS server with different IP address

Tags: linux, networking, dns

i have a DNS server with the following zone kevin.com: 192.168.1.11 and marry.com: 192.168.1.210 in `/etc/named.conf`

```
zone "kevin.com" {
    type master;
    file "forward.kevin.com";
};
zone "marry.com"
{
    type master;
    file "forward.marry.com";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" 
{
    type master;
    file "reverse.kevin.com; reverse.marry.com";
};
```

The forward.kevin.com file:

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA server1.kevin.com. root.kevin.com. (
         2011071001   ;   Serial
                604800  ;   Refresh
                86400   ;   Retry
                2419200 ;   Expire
          86400 ;   Minimum Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  kevin.com.
@   IN  A   192.168.1.11
server1 IN A 192.168.1.11
```

The reverse.kevin.com

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA server1.kevin.com. root.kevin.com. (
                2011071001   ;   Serial
                604800  ;   Refresh
                86400   ;   Retry
                2419200 ;   Expire
                86400 ;   Minimum Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  server1.kevin.com.
@  IN  PTR vnlab.com.
server1 IN A 192.168.1.11
11 IN PTR server1.kevin.com.
```

The forward.marry.com

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA server1.marry.com. root.marry.com. (
                2011071001   ;   Serial
                604800  ;   Refresh
                86400   ;   Retry
                2419200 ;   Expire
               86400 ;   Minimum Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  server1.kevin.com.
@   IN  A   192.168.1.11
server1 IN A 192.168.1.210
```

The reverse.marry.com

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA server1.marry.com. root.marry.com. (
                2011071001   ;   Serial
                604800  ;   Refresh
                86400   ;   Retry
                2419200 ;   Expire
                604800 ;   Minimum Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  server1.marry.com.
@  IN  PTR marry.com
server1 IN A 192.168.1.210
210 IN PTR server1.marry.com
```

When i try to `service named restart` i got the error

```
Loading from master file reverse.kevin.com; reverse.marry.com; failed: file not found
```

Help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a guess, hence only a comment. The `file` directive can probably take just a one filename or the quotation marks mess the config up. Your config instructs the BIND to look for a file called (literally) `reverse.kevin.com; reverse.marry.com`, which of course fails.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the A-record from the reverse file. Only ptr records are allowed in reverse lookup zonefiles.